# Infinitive form Vs. -ing form after a value judgement

Tags: syntax, infinitives, gerunds

Which one of the following is correct and why?

> It'll be wonderful **to see** you again.
>   It'll be wonderful **seeing** you again.

Comment: Welcome, Aslan! I'm pretty sure "to see" is grammatical, but I don't know why. Nevertheless, I share with you this question. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct. Either the gerund clause or the infinitive clause can act syntactically as a [NominalPhrase] in this construction.

The construction *it* + *BE* + *[AdjectivalPhrase]* + *[NominalPhrase]* is a rearrangement of the ordinary sentence *[NominalPhrase]* + *BE* + *[AdjectivalPhrase]* which focuses on the *[AdjectivalPhrase]*.

> To see you again'll be wonderful ... > ... It'll be wonderful to see you again.
>   Seeing you again'll be wonderful ... > ... It'll be wonderful seeing you again.

The pronoun *it* refers to the longish [NominalPhrase], and it's put at the head of the sentence so you can give the [AdjectivalPhrase] *wonderful* a more **focal** position, before [NominalPhrase] which is tacked on at the end to clarify what *it* is.

ADDED:
Note that when an ordinary noun phrase rather than a clause is employed as the [NominalPhrase], it must be separated from what goes before with a comma or dash:

> Paris in the spring will be wonderful ... > ... It'll be wonderful, Paris in the spring.